# How do I remove a navigation property from a model in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to change a model in EF Core by removing a navigation property but when I do that the project won't build for me to add a migration. I understand why but as I'm no expert with Fluent API, I'm not sure of the best way to remove the property.

The property I'm trying to remove is the Images property (I want to change it to a one-to-one relationship rather than one-to-many).

```
public partial class DiaryEntries
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public long DiaryId { get; set; }

    public Diaries Diary { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
}    

public partial class Images
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long DiaryEntryId { get; set; }

    public DiaryEntries DiaryEntry { get; set; }
}
```

The code that defines the relationship is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Images>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Images", "dbo");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.DiaryEntryId)
                .HasName("IX_FK_DiaryEntryImages");

            entity.Property(e => e.DiaryEntryId).HasColumnName("DiaryEntry_Id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Filename).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Title).HasMaxLength(128);
            
            entity.HasOne(d => d.DiaryEntry)
                .WithMany(p => p.Images)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.DiaryEntryId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_DiaryEntryImages");
        });
```

Obviously, if I remove the `ICollection<Images> Images` navigation property from the model, then it will no longer exist and will cause an error in the code above. So, what's the best way to remove a navigation property?

Comment: What problem are you facing while deleting "ICollection<Images> Images" ?

Comment: If I delete it, the p.Images in the relation in modelBuilder obviously causes an error because it's no longer in the model. I'm trying to find out what the best practice is when trying to remove a navigation property.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you want a 1-1 relationship? A diary can have more than one image right?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me why you want a 1-1 relationship? A diary can have more than one image right?
To answer the question though, just remove the last block from your fluent api as well as the navigation property.
If you want to change to a one to one - your fluent api should look like this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Images>()
        .HasOne(a => a.Diary)
        .WithOne(b => b.Images)
        .HasForeignKey<Diary>(b => b.DiaryId);
```

As an additional point, your class names should be singular rather than plural :-)